# How to save password for AppStore on mac？

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, password

It seems that the setting doesn't work. It's unnecessary and annoying to input the password for free APPs times and times again.

Answer (score 1):

Password settings are in System Preferences > App Store

[image]

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't work. It acts like saving password for only 15 minutes for all APPs.